# Access image in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image

Can I create a Controller that simply returns an image?

I would like to route this logic through a controller, whenever a variable `[LOGO]` such requested,

The controller will look up `logo.png` and replace the image to the variable `[LOGO]`.

I don't want to use a View. I want to do it all with just the Controller.

Is this possible?

I tried some way by following code,

```
EmailHelper.SendEmail(
    Constants.EmailSender.CandidateSupport,
    candidate.Email,
    Constants.EmailSubject.CandidateUpdateProfile,
    Constants.EmailBody.CandidateUpdateProfile
    .Replace("[LOGO]", Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo_small2.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you need, but in answer to "Can I create a Controller that simply returns an image?" you can do this as follows:

```
public FileResult Image(string filePath)
{
    //get your stream
    return File(stream, "image/png");
}
```

Obviously you'd need to think about security given that you are returning items from the file system.

Comment: I don't need this type. I want to retrieve image from controller. No need to return items anything.

Comment: Then it would be good if you could clarify what you want - what do you mean by "retrieve image from controller"?

Comment: ok. Actually i create one model for "disclaimer" wth email. In that model I create some variables and just use replace method in controller then i access. In this case, i have to send the mail with "Logo". In that model, within @"<span>"+ only i assign values. But Image tag is not working here. so I create one variable for [ImageLink].Then I replace the variable [ImageLink] to the path like .replace("[ImageLink]",Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo_small2.png")) likethat. This is my problem. No one find out this..If anyone means pls help me.

Comment: Sounds like you should not be solving this problem with the normal MVC pipeline, not a good fit.